# Delayed choice measurement subsequent analysis

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This is a variant associated with the Scully and Druhl signal-idler photon delayed choice experiment, as described and discussed in Brian Greene's Fabric of the Cosmos.

The commentary notes the "delay" may be configured to happen a very (years) long time after the photons pass the two slit/splitter. It is stressed that the future measurements do not change the pathway decision "today" but clearly there is a linkage in some "spooky" way.

My thought is that it should be possible to set up the "eraser" in such a way that the which-path information contained in the "tagged" idler photon is obscured when it hits the detector "tomorrow" and is recorded, but that in some years time when some technology enhancement is enabled, the recorded detector information can subsequently extract the which-path information (a bit like DNA analysis being used on cold cases).  The outcome being that when the initial observation/measurement is made, the interference pattern should remain, but at a subsequent time it should be possible to identify the path taken by an individual photon.

I realise that this is a hypothetical/thought experiment, but I would think it is quite realistically achievable.

Comment: There is not question here?

Answer (score 2):

The linkage isn't particularly spooky. Record *all* of the flashes from the 2-slit pattern, and store the polarization for each one in some long-lived qubit.

Peek at the flashes you see, and you'll see two overlapping bell curves, the "no interference" case looking like $|f(z - z_1)|^2 + |f(z - z_2)|^2$.

If you measure the qubits in one basis -- let's say that it's been rotated to the computational basis $\big\{|0\rangle, |1\rangle\big\},$ then you find out that you can color these "red" and "blue", and the "red" curve is the bell curve $|f(z - z_1)|^2$ and the "blue" curve is the bell curve $|f(z - z_2)|^2$: you have measured "which-way."

If you measure the qubits in the other basis, which in this case is the Hadamard basis $\big\{|+\rangle, |-\rangle\big\} = \big\{|0\rangle + |1\rangle, |0\rangle-|1\rangle\big\},$you see instead two "interference patterns", with "red" looking like the 2-slit interference pattern $|f(z - z_1) + f(z - z_2)|^2$ but "blue" looking like the phase-rotated 2-slit interference pattern $|f(z - z_1) - f(z - z_2)|^2$. Now you have measured "which phase" rather than "which direction".

Are those inconsistent? No: they both sum up to the same two-curves end result. It's just that some of the photons you can definitively state which path they took through the double-slit experiment, and some you can't, because you chose a different thing to measure.

The bottom line is that this particular sentence is wrong:

> The outcome being that when the initial observation/measurement is made, the interference pattern should remain.

The interference pattern, in the quantum eraser experiment, **doesn't** remain: it has to be extracted by correlating individual photodetections with the results of the stored qubits. If you collect all of the information, you see the *classical* result, and it's only by throwing away half of the flashes (usually the ones corresponding to $|-\rangle$) that anyone "erases" the interference pattern.

Comment: thanks - yes I was sloppy with that sentence.  But doesn't the key point remain, that having been extracted, at some subsequent time, which-path information can be extracted from the past measurement?

Comment: If you have extracted it then you have extracted it. If you haven't you haven't. If you choose to extract the phase information you will for sure throw away the which-way information.